# During compiling, it fails at "cannot find -lexecinfo"

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, cmake, cc, slackware

This is Slackware 14.1 Linux.
During compiling it always fail at

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lexecinfo
```

Is there a library missing?
The problem is I don't know the exact file name it's looking for, I have a

```
     /usr/include/execinfo.h
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's ld, the linker, which is unable to find that library. Most probably it looks for `libexecinfo.so` and similar but cannot find it. Try to install it if you don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is trying to use backtrace(3) or the like, then it's likely you do not actually need the -lexecinfo option to compile the source.  Edit your Makefile and try removing it as see if it will build.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Steve's answer, glibc contains `backtrace` and friends, which are GNU extensions. Therefore, on glibc systems, no extra linker flag is needed to get the `backtrace` symbols, so you should remove the `-lexecinfo` flag.

However, non-glibc systems can use an external libexecinfo to provide these symbols, in which case `-lexecinfo` is needed.